# BigQuery (BQ) - Drop Partition

Tags: date, google-bigquery, partition

I'm using the BQ CLI (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool).

I didn't find how to **Delete DAY Partition** data.

For example, i have a DAY PARTITIONED table that holds data for dates 2016-09-01 and until 2016-09-30.

I need to delete the "2016-09-15" partition completely.

Is this possible through CLI command ?

Comment: were you able to delete a partition of your choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely do not have to delete it to re-insert the data. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#restating_data_in_a_partition) for details about how to re-state data in a specific portion of your date partitioned table.

Basically, just use the `--replace` flag with the `$YYYYMMDD` table decorator with the bq CLI tool.

Answer (score 5):

If you do want to delete a partition you can use the `bq rm` command while specifying a `$YYYYMMDD` table decorator. For your case the command would look like:

```
bq rm -t 'dataset.table$20160915'
```

Be careful to include the **single** quotes, otherwise the decorator may get expanded to an empty variable and you'll delete the full table.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way we can Update it Through CLI:-

```
bq update --time_partitioning_expiration (time in second) Dataset.table_name
```

Comment: With partitioned table:

```BigQuery error in update operation: Cannot change partitioning/clustering spec for a partitioned/clustered table.```


With non partitioned table:

```Cannot convert non partitioned table to partitioned table.```

Comment: Try:
```bq update
--default_partition_expiration integer
project_id:dataset```

Answer (score 1):

For people like myself who clicked for the title **BigQuery (BQ) - Drop Partition** but are looking to do it with api.

You drop a partition the same way you delete a table only adding `${partrition}` to the end, i.e. `my.table.id$20230101`. ([api doc for deleting a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/delete))

example using python:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client.delete_table('my.table.id$20230101')
```

and a if anyone else wants to delete daily partritions

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from datetime import date

def delete_day_partition(table_id: str, day: date):
    """
    https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/delete
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087763/is-there-a-way-of-deleting-old-partitions-in-a-partitioned-table-using-bigquery
    """
    client = bigquery.Client()
    day = day.strftime('%Y%m%d')  # date() -> 'YYYYMMDD'
    partition = f'{table_id}${day}'
    client.delete_table(partition)

delete_day_partition('my.table.id', date(2023, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Select the project in which the dataset (and thus table) exists**

```
gcloud config set project <project-name>
```

Note: You can see the full list of available projects using `gcloud projects list`

**Step 2: Delete the desired partition**

```
bq rm -t 'dataset.table$partition'
```

---

Otherwise, you can even delete a partition from a table even when working on a separate project. But in this case you'd have to specify it in the command:

```
bq rm -t project_id:dataset.table$partition
```