# Is there a way of deleting old partitions in a partitioned table using bigquery API?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a daily partitioned table, and I want to delete older partitions by API.

The documentation only says that older partitions which are not updated for 3 months are stored with 50% discount. Thanks Google, but I really do not intend to keep those data for half a century.

I thought the whole point of partitioned tables was to allow deleting old data, but all I find is a discount. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: I am waiting for the feature as well. DML statements that modify partitioned tables are not yet supported. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language

Comment: You won't have to wait a half century. :) BigQuery has a limit of 4000 partitions (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#partitioned_tables) so you'll max out just under 11 years.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tables: delete](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/delete) API to delete specific partition of the table by specifying that partition as yourTable$YYYYMMDD

And you can use [timePartitioning.expirationMs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#timePartitioning) property to set `Number of milliseconds for which to keep the storage for a partition`. You can set this property either while creating table via [Tables: insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert) API or you can patch existing table via [Tables: patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch) API

Comment: Deleting tables via yourTable$YYYYMMDD does not seem to update the table's partition lists when accessed via select * from [datawarehouse:dev.temps$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]

Comment: Yes. this might be a bug to be reported to BigQuery Team. Meantime actual table is updated in a sense that no anymore rows in deleted partition and thus no cost for it. you can check it via: SELECT _PARTITIONTIME AS partition_id, COUNT(1) FROM [datawarehouse:dev.temps]

Comment: Note also that when deleting partitions, cached queries that include that partition are not invalidated; see https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=894